# Cucumber transform to exclude cucumber table

Tags: ruby, cucumber

I wanted a transform in my cucumber framework where whenever I give 'test test', I should get test_test in my step def.

I wrote a transform as below :

`SPACE_TO_UNDERSCORE = Transform /^([^"]* [^"]*)$/ do |string|
  string.tr!(" ", "_")
end`

Which makes my step :

`And the user selects yes to "dual nationality" on "edit user" details page`

to

`And(/^the user selects yes to "([^"]*)" on "([^"]*)" details page$/) do |field,page|
  # field is now dual_nationality
  # page is now edit_user 
end`

it works but the only problem is it also captures the cucumber tables steps like 
below and converts the `table` to `table:case_number` string. `table` is `Cucumber::MultilineArgument::DataTable` if i don't use the transform. so obviously the transform is affecting the table if it matches its contents.

Is there a way to do that in `transform` where you can exclude table content ?

`When the user loads a url with below case details
      | case number |
      | 154745      |`

`When(/^the user loads a url with below case details$/) do |table|
  #table => "table:case_number"
end`

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest not writing scenario steps like this and avoiding transforms. Your step explain 'HOW' the user says they are a dual national. It has no need to do this. Consider:

```
Given the user has dual nationality
Given I am a dual national
When the user confirms their dual nationality
When I confirm my dual nationality
```

There are of course many other ways to word this.

All these steps require no transforms, and no regex's and can easily be implemented by doing something like

```
find_by_css('#dual_national').set(true)
```

Assuming you have a dual_national checkbox.

In general every time you put detail in your scenarios about "HOW" you do things you just make live harder for yourself. There is no need to use tables, transforms or even (most of the time) regex's when using Cucumber